# If condition not working in componentDidUpdate react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

// I am comparing the response from reducer after successful submission of form.How can I set alert to true after getting success response.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.tempData!==prevProps.tempData) {
    this.setState(() => this.setState({ alert: true }));
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {  tempData: state.CourseReducer['result'] };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { postRetriver })(
TextField
);

//reducer
export const CourseReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SET_COURSE') {
   // console.log(action.payload)-->{status: 200, data: "Updated Successfully"}
    return { ...state, "result":action.payload };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Comment: Can you `console.log` both props and post the output?

Comment: console.log(this.props.tempData ) -->{status: 200, data: "Updated Successfully"}
console.log(prevProps.tempData)--> {status: 200, data: "Updated Successfully"}

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a function to `setState` it needs to return the object to set, not another `setState`. So this row:

```
this.setState(() => this.setState({ alert: true }));
```

Should probably be like this:

```
this.setState({ alert: true });
```

Comment: The if condition is itself not valid so the state is not set.